# getGsmBitErrorRate always returns 255 on Android

Tags: android, parameters, gsm

I need to get BER on Android, and I'm using the method **getGsmBitErrorRate** of a SignalStrength like this

```
public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

        Log.e("onSignalStrengthsChanged: ", "GSM Cinr = "
                + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()); 
    }
```

inside a PhoneStateListener.

According TS 27.007 8.5, the expected return id  **(0-7, 99)** , but in my app, it's only returning **255**!

Is there any interpretation of this number, or it's really wrong?
and if its wrong, any ideia of why it's returning it?

thks