# Does getGsmBitErrorRate() actually work?

Tags: android, gsm

There are multiple old threads about [`SignalStrength#getGsmBitErrorRate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmBitErrorRate%28%29) returning bogus values like [-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864624/getgsmbiterrorrate-always-returns-1) or [255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975787/getgsmbiterrorrate-always-returns-255-on-android).  It always returns 0 in my tests on a Motorola Moto G (4.4.2), which is at least a valid value, but possibly still fake.

Is there any evidence that this method actually works at all?